# How do I view the full build log on xcode5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I'm getting an error from lipo and I'd like to see all the steps leading up to it.

The xcode UI is only showing me the errors themselves. Is this located as a text file or can xcode 5 show the complete log some how?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Go to the Log navigator in Xcode...

[image]

choose the build which you want to examine...

[image]

then control-click on the "Build target AppName" line in the editor...

[image]

You'll get a context menu which includes the option "Expand All Transcripts".

[image]

Comment: Where is the build log located on disk?

Comment: To open build log in another editor, you can enter log navigator, select a build, select one or more "Build target ..." entries, right click, and select copy. Then paste into other editor. Seems hacky IMO.