# What does the error 'Unsupported Configuration' mean?

Tags: xcode, swift, configuration

When I go to the screen that is causing this error, their is a white screen. It should have a website on it. Ive read the error but I don't know how to fix it. Any help? The [Picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1sGa_ZrCtLfnlmsswQbzPAEYCDH906h7eH9IfUhQQv5I/edit?usp=sharing) shows what it says.

**Update:** The warnings have went away but I still get a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

Look underneath the error and read what it says:

> Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn
>   off this constraint in the current configuration.

It seems as though you had some items in your storyboarrd window that had some constraints set on them, and then those items were deleted. The constraints seem to still be set.

If you remove those constraints, this error should disappear.

If you cannot find those constraints, refer to this question's answer:

[Xcode Storyboard warning: Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547399/xcode-storyboard-warning-constraint-referencing-items-turned-off-in-current-con)

Comment: The warnings have went away but I still get a white screen.

Comment: You get a white screen when you run the application?

Comment: Well, I get it when I click the button. Instead of displaying what it should, it "hides" everything on it.  @ecatalano

Comment: but if I need those constraints?