# Xcode 8. Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints, xcode8

I've faced with the problem after updating to Xcode 8. Every time after UI objects are deleted from the main storyboard I get the following warning:

> Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration.

[image]

It looks like this is an Xcode bug, but anyway I want to remove these warnings from the project. I found that there were the same problem with Xcode 6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547399/xcode-storyboard-warning-constraint-referencing-items-turned-off-in-current-con/) but no answer from that question fix the problem right no. So when I find the incorrect constraint in the storyboard and delete it the amount of incorrect constrains is increasing instead of decreasing. I things that I've also tried:

- cleaned the project
- cleaned the derived data
- deleted all constraints and added new ones from the scratch

Any ideas?

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @MuruganandhamK unfortunately no

Comment: @MuruganandhamK check if you having any views left unchecked `Installed`

Comment: **Note that in general this issue is caused by: you have an item which is un-Installed, but, it has constraints which are still installed.** In general, find the un-Installed item, and for all of its constraints, mark them un-Installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Storyboard warning: Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547399/xcode-storyboard-warning-constraint-referencing-items-turned-off-in-current-con)

Comment: This is indeed an exact dupe of the linked question (thank goodness!)  the only confusion was that at one point, Danny was plain "deleting the constraints" (obviously you can't do that in iOS, unrelated to this problem at hand).

Comment: you can find uninstalled view easily by looking in document outline, uninstalled view will be of gray color

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was having several views that were not `Installed`, after updating to xcode 8.1, I had 2 warnings.

Following steps worked for me:

1) Clean the project and restart Xcode, warnings decreased to 1.

2) Selecting the warning will show exactly which constraint having an issue. Open `Attributes Inspector` and select those views where constraint is applied, look for `Installed` if its unchecked on the view (not on constraint). You can either **select Installed on the view**, or **unselect Installed on constraint itself**.

See screenshot below. `Installed` was unchecked on view, not on the constraint that the warning was pointing to :)

[image: Installed is unchecked on a view, not on constraint itself]

Update: Same issue again with another ViewController, a UIView was not Installed for a size class, I unselect Installed on constraint itself and warning is gone too, I guess its not an Xcode bug, its claiming to turn Installed on/off on both UIView and Constrarint

Comment: All my constraints where already installed. So this didn't help. About cleaning project and restarting it as I wrote in my question, I've already tried it and it didn't help.

Comment: @Danny, please check the view where the constraint is attached, not the constraint itself, in your case the view might even be installed, just check in case :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But what does install checkbox do with UI elements?

Comment: @Danny, Glad it helped, disabling installed will cause it to behave as if you didn't add that UI element at all

Answer (score 12):

The short answer: Inspect the source code for your storyboard for each of the ids in your warnings by searching 'id="*theIdFromWarning"*.  The ids are for the *constraints*.  When you find the constraint id, it will reference the two element ids.  Search for the elements by searching 'id="*theIdForElement*"' Then you'll find the name or some piece of info in that element source code to find out what element you're looking at.  Then switch the storyboard back from source code to the interface builder, find the two elements, and see which size class the related constraint is installed but the element isn't.  Example: ViewA.right could be horizontally constrained to ViewB.left, installed on all size classes, but ViewA might only be installed on height=Regular size class.  Solution: Install ViewA on all size classes, or uninstall the constraint on all size classes and add the constraint to only the height=Regular size class.

Longer answer, step-by-step:

I was not able to easily see what constraints/elements these warnings were referring to.  For me, I was able to right click the warning, and select "Reveal in log". This revealed 10 warnings in this style format:

`/my/filepath/to/storyboard:1xe-xx-Bx5: warning: Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration.  Turn off this constraint in the current configuration.`

If your log doesn't show a detailed description like this, then right-click on any log reference to `Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration.  Turn off this constraint in the current configuration.` warning and select `Expand all transcripts`, then search your log file for the constraint descriptions.

So, I opened my storyboard, right clicked the storyboard file in the project navigator and selected 'view as source code' searched for every constraint by the listed id (in the above example, I searched for the id:**1xe-xx-Bx5**), and found one reference to it:

`<constraint firstItem="Mwb-6O-DKs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y2M-Sk-Ygh" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="19" id="1ce-xx-Bx5"/>`

What this tells me is:

- That the constraint has an id of **1ce-xx-Bx5**
- The constraint is associated with two elements:
- One has the id of **Mwb-6O-DKs**
- The other has the id of **y2M-Sk-Ygh**

So I searched the source code for the first element by id, by searching for `id="Mwb-6O-DKs"` and found this:

`<label ...(truncating for readability sake)...text="Build Label"...(truncating for readability sake)...id="Mwb-6O-DKs">`

This tells me that the first element is a `UILabel` with the title 'Build Label'.

Searching for the second element by id, `id="y2M-Sk-Ygh"`, revealed:

`<viewController storyboardIdentifier="login"...(truncating for readability sake)...<layoutGuides><viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y2M-Sk-Ygh"/>`

So I take this to mean that the `UILabel` with the text "Build Label" has a top constraint that is turned off. (since the `viewControllerLayoutGuide` constraint should never be turned off, it must be the `UILabel`.

Lo and behold, it was not installed.  I selected the `Installed` checkbox for the UILabel, and the error disappeared.

1 down, 9 more to go!  (F*ing Xcode...)

Answer (score 4):

Show the `Report Navigator` [That is the rightmost tab on the leftmost column]. This will show build log with constraint ids. For further details, look into this [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501641/327565).

Comment: If you carefully read my question, you'll see that I have a reference in it to the same stakeoverflow question that you have indicated, and I wrote that none of the ways to solve the problem there helped me to solve the problem

Comment: @Munahil is correct: it's the identical problem.  You have to (1) totally delete the item in question, (2) simply ensure that all constraints are "un-Installed" if the item is "un-Installed".  Note that - of course - you can't just "delete the constraint" as that will (obviously) bring about other layout errors.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason**

**You have an item (i.e. view) which is un-Installed, but, it has constraints which are still installed.** (commented by [fattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/fattie))

**How to find out specific constraint**

It is difficult to find **exact constraint** which causes this warning. It mentioned step by step in [BastiBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501641/2666902) how to find out the specific constraint.

**Solution**

- Check both the items/views(first & second ) of the specific constraint whether any item is un-Install for any specific size-class. In my case the constraint was installed for all size-classes, but one of the item was installed for "wC hR" (Ref following image).
  [image]
- Install the item to resolve the warning.
- Now, build the app, if you still find the same warning for that specific interface/XIB file, don't worry this time some other constraints have the same problem.

**Advice for Future**

- Please check whether views are properly installed while copy/paste them from other interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had a view that I had uninstalled so the warning appeared. After reinstalling the view, the warning did not go away, even after a clean. But after restarting Xcode the warning went away.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the view or constraint by looking at tag in the storyboard source.

1. Open the storyboard as source
2. Look for the following tag to get the id
3. Look for the id in the storyboard to find which item it is.

Comment: this was the best advice - got straight to where the problem was

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to delete the uninstalled views. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem there are a few options:

**First what causes the problem?** 
Uninstalling a view without uninstalling it's constraints.

**Second why would you so this?**
You might want a view to remain in your view controller because you built it and then the specs changed so you wanted to remove it temporarily because perhaps that portion wasn't included in your current sprint or what have you

**Last how does one solve it?**

There are three options:

1. **If you can just reinstall the view**
2. **If you want to keep the view**
3. **If you can just delete the uninstalled view all together**

**Option 1**

**If you can just reinstall the view:**

1. Reinstall the view by toggling the installed option as seen in picture 2 on any view that is faded out as seen in picture 1
2. Try to clean the project(Command +Shift+K) - if that doesn't work, try a restart of xCode. If that doesn't work, you might have missed an uninstalled view somewhere.

**Option 2**

**If you want to keep the view:**

1. Find every view in your view controller system that is faded out (this means it has been uninstalled)

1 [image]2 [image]

2. Look at the constraints associated with the view

3[image]

3. Uncheck "Installed"

The constraint will now also be faded (not the constraint group) as seen in the first picture.

4. Try to clean the project(Command +Shift+K) - if that doesn't work, try a restart of xCode. If that doesn't work, you might have missed a constraint somewhere.

**Option 3**

**If you can just delete the uninstalled view all together**

1. Delete any views that have been uninstalled which will automatically delete their constraints
2. Clean the project (Command +Shift+K), if that doesn't work, try restarting xCode.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, make sure that you 'uninstall' all constraints for 'uninstalled' views/buttons/etc.