# Print Pre-action script in console

Tags: swift, xcode, bash

For testing purposes I am using a Pre-Action Script for my tests (*that cleans a database for Webservices tests*).

For now I am printing the output inside a file located in my test folder, following this SO post ( [Xcode scheme pre-action script not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482457/xcode-scheme-pre-action-script-not-running) ).

```
# Pre Build Output
exec > ${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProjectTests/TestLogs.log 2>&1
echo "=== PRE-ACTION SCRIPT ==="

...
```

However this is not really handy to have to open a log file via command line whenever a test set is launched to see what happened.

Is there a way to redirect Pre-Action script's output directly inside XCode console?

Thanks a lot