# Have XCode start web server before running tests

Tags: ios, testing, xcode6

I have an iphone app that uses a rails backend to grab data from. Is it possible to have a before start hook for tests that start the rails server?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the pre-action in the Test command? You'll need to hit that + and add the New Run Script Action.

[image]

The only drawback is you can't abort the test if you cannot start the test. You can see a thread about that here: [Is it normal for Xcode not to detect if a pre-action failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419927/is-it-normal-for-xcode-not-to-detect-if-a-pre-action-failed)