# Xcode13 how to see pre and post build action logs?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode13

similar question to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419927/is-it-normal-for-xcode-not-to-detect-if-a-pre-action-failed) but that thread is very outdated (Xocde4)

on Xcode13. How do you see logs of a pre and post build action? I am running a script as part of the pre-build action but logs can't be found anymore. [image]

I am not even sure its kicked off - how do I check pre build action its actually invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved a similar issue by forwarding my pre-build logs to a file. I added the next bunch of code to the beginning of my pre-build script.

```
#/bin/bash
exec > "${PROJECT_DIR}/prebuild.log" 2>&1
set -o pipefail
set -e
```